# startActivityForResult() is not being invoked

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I'm new to android and i am writing a photo album app. I am trying to get an image from the user and store it in an album.  Here are my code snippets from my AlbumOptions activity:

```
public void add(View v){
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "Choose Photo To Add"),RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null)
    {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        final String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();

        //get a name for the photo
        final EditText pName = new EditText(this);
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("Create Album")
                .setMessage("Enter album name:")
                .setView(pName)
                .setPositiveButton("Add Photo", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        String name = pName.getText().toString();

                        //check if photo name already exists, if not create it
                        if(!album.checkName(name))
                        {
                            Photo p = new Photo(name, picturePath, "");
                            photoList.add(p);
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                        //prompt error that photo name is taken
                        else
                        {
                            AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(AlbumOptions.this).create();
                            alertDialog.setTitle("Error");
                            alertDialog.setMessage("Photo name already exists!");
                            alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                            dialog.dismiss();
                                        }
                                    });
                            alertDialog.show();
                        }
                    }
                });

    }
}
```

The add method is invoked when the user clicks the add button to add a photo to the open album. However, when using the debugger tool, the program passes over `startActivityForResult()` call. I've looked through various posts to see what is going wrong and I can't figure out what is going wrong. `RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE` is > 0, and I checked my manifest file as suggested by many of the posts I've seen. Any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: does it goes to pick?

Comment: it pops up photos to select, but if after I select one, it does nothing

Comment: Have you logged anything within `onActivityResult`? Is this code in a Fragment or an Activity?

Comment: The code is all in my AlbumOptions Activity, I used code from this source with minor alterations in `onActivityResult` : http://viralpatel.net/blogs/pick-image-from-galary-android-app/

Comment: please provide full code. there may be problem in requestcode & others. also the view parameter in add method seems confusing

Comment: how did you verify its not called, you have no code written in onActivityResult

Comment: @ColdFire using the debugger tool to step through the code

Comment: @ZahanSafallwa  I posted the rest of the code for `onActivityResult`

Comment: what is your activity launchMode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code.Might this will help you.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode==SELECT_IMAGE){
        if(resultCode==RESULT_OK && null!=data){
              //do whatever you want.
          }
    }
```

first change the @Override public to @Override protected.  and also set this.

```
   Intent image=new Intent();
   image.setType("image/*");
   image.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
   startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(image,"select file"),SELECT_IMAGE);
```

**Change this line .You have pointed that RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE is > 0, change this to =0;**

```
public int SELECT_IMAGE=0;
```

Comment: Still gives the same behavior

Comment: Seems to have worked, could you explain why changing it to 0 would change anything ?

Comment: because when we compare two values it should be exact match , where you have assigned  SELECT_IMAGE > 0 takes any value. thats why it mis match to the condition.